# mysql syntax error on creating stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

There are tons of similar posts, but still couldn't solve the error.

Here's my stored procedure query:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spa_gui_get_next_task;
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE `spa_gui_get_next_task`(IN var_user_id INT(11), IN var_task_id INT(11))
  BEGIN  
    -- create temp table
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_user_tasks engine=memory
        SELECT
           tsk.id,
           tsk.request_id,
           tsk.sys_index,
           tsk.category_group,
           tsk.category,
           tsk.is_assigned,
           tsk.hash_id 
        FROM
           user_tasks as usr 
           inner join
              unassigned_tasks as tsk 
              on usr.task_id = tsk.id 
        WHERE
          usr.assigned_to = var_user_id
        AND 
            tsk.product_id NOT IN ( SELECT product_id FROM product_progresses WHERE request_id = tsk.request_id )
        AND 
            BINARY hash_id NOT IN ( SELECT hash_id FROM product_match_unmatches WHERE request_id = tsk.request_id AND (is_matched=1 OR auto_unmatched_by IS NOT NULL) )
        ORDER BY tsk.id;

    -- fetch next row
    SELECT qs.*
    FROM temp_table_user_tasks as qs
    WHERE qs.id = ( SELECT min(qs.id) FROM temp_table_user_tasks as qt WHERE qt.id > var_task_id);

    -- drop temp table
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table_user_tasks;
  END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting this error:

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE `spa_gui_get_next_task`(IN var_user_id INT(11), ' at line 1
```

Also the same query is working on `phpmyadmin 10.1.26-MariaDB`, and even tried exporting the same stored procedure from `phpmyadmin` to another `mysql v5.7.12`.

Comment: How are you running the query?

Comment: in a query editor.

Comment: Perhaps the query editor doesn't support multiple queries? Or you have already used a `DELIMITER //` and not changed the delimiter back to `;`?

Comment: As nick suggested try `DELIMITER ;` before the line `drop proc....`